# How to create Masked TextBox like windows IP address fields

Tags: c#, wpf

How to create a `numeric Masked TextBox` in `WPF` that  like windows IP Address fields, jump to next area after hit `.(DOT)` button

[image: Windows IP Address field]

Comment: have you made any attempt to do so yourself?

Comment: I have no Idea where to begin. I use Extended WPF Toolkit for Masked text box, I searched through their documentation but attain no clue. have any Idea?

Comment: This is not a code creation service. It is for asking specific, questions about something you are trying to do yourself

Comment: I didnt ask the whole code.just like everyone else i asked a question about a part of a control and people share their ideas. if you have any idea to solve my problem write it .thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I used a `UserControl` for this. I'm sure it's not the most perfect one ever, but maybe it is a good starting point for you.

`UserControl` XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="IPTextBoxDemo.IPTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="300"
             FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBoxBase">
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" 
                                Name="border" 
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                          Name="PART_ContentHost" 
                                          Focusable="False" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />

            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />

            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />

            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="FirstSegment" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Center" MaxLength="3" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                 TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged" PreviewKeyDown="UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown" DataObject.Pasting="DataObject_OnPasting" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="." TextAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="False"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="SecondSegment" Grid.Column="2" TextAlignment="Center" MaxLength="3" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged" PreviewKeyDown="UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown" DataObject.Pasting="DataObject_OnPasting" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Text="." TextAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="False"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="ThirdSegment" Grid.Column="4" TextAlignment="Center" MaxLength="3" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged" PreviewKeyDown="UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown" DataObject.Pasting="DataObject_OnPasting" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="5" Text="." TextAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="False" />

        <TextBox x:Name="LastSegment" Grid.Column="6" TextAlignment="Center" MaxLength="3" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged" PreviewKeyDown="UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown" DataObject.Pasting="DataObject_OnPasting" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The XAML consists of a main `Grid` with seven columns, four for for `TextBox`es where you will enter your number and three for the fixed dots in the IP address.

The `UserControl` code-behind:

```
namespace IPTextBoxDemo
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Input;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for IPTextBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class IPTextBox : UserControl
    {
        private static readonly List<Key> DigitKeys = new List<Key> { Key.D0, Key.D1, Key.D2, Key.D3, Key.D4, Key.D5, Key.D6, Key.D7, Key.D8, Key.D9 };
        private static readonly List<Key> MoveForwardKeys = new List<Key> { Key.Right };
        private static readonly List<Key> MoveBackwardKeys = new List<Key> { Key.Left };
        private static readonly List<Key> OtherAllowedKeys = new List<Key> { Key.Tab, Key.Delete };

        private readonly List<TextBox> _segments = new List<TextBox>();

        private bool _suppressAddressUpdate = false;

        public IPTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _segments.Add(FirstSegment);
            _segments.Add(SecondSegment);
            _segments.Add(ThirdSegment);
            _segments.Add(LastSegment);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AddressProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Address", typeof (string), typeof (IPTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), AddressChanged)
            {
                BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
            });

        private static void AddressChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ipTextBox = dependencyObject as IPTextBox;
            var text = e.NewValue as string;

            if (text != null && ipTextBox != null)
            {
                ipTextBox._suppressAddressUpdate = true;
                var i = 0;
                foreach (var segment in text.Split('.'))
                {
                    ipTextBox._segments[i].Text = segment;
                    i++;
                }
                ipTextBox._suppressAddressUpdate = false;
            }
        }

        public string Address
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(AddressProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AddressProperty, value); }
        }

        private void UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DigitKeys.Contains(e.Key))
            {
                e.Handled = ShouldCancelDigitKeyPress();
                HandleDigitPress();
            }
            else if(MoveBackwardKeys.Contains(e.Key))
            {
                e.Handled = ShouldCancelBackwardKeyPress();
                HandleBackwardKeyPress();
            }
            else if (MoveForwardKeys.Contains(e.Key))
            {
                e.Handled = ShouldCancelForwardKeyPress();
                HandleForwardKeyPress();
            } else if (e.Key == Key.Back)
            {
                HandleBackspaceKeyPress();
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.OemPeriod)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                HandlePeriodKeyPress();
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = !AreOtherAllowedKeysPressed(e);
            }
        }

        private bool AreOtherAllowedKeysPressed(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            return e.Key == Key.C && ((e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) != 0) ||
                   e.Key == Key.V && ((e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) != 0) ||
                   e.Key == Key.A && ((e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) != 0) ||
                   e.Key == Key.X && ((e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) != 0) ||
                   OtherAllowedKeys.Contains(e.Key);
        }

        private void HandleDigitPress()
        {
            var currentTextBox = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as TextBox;

            if (currentTextBox != null && currentTextBox.Text.Length == 3 &&
                currentTextBox.CaretIndex == 3 && currentTextBox.SelectedText.Length == 0)
            {
                MoveFocusToNextSegment(currentTextBox);
            }
        }

        private bool ShouldCancelDigitKeyPress()
        {
            var currentTextBox = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as TextBox;
            return currentTextBox != null && 
                   currentTextBox.Text.Length == 3 && 
                   currentTextBox.CaretIndex == 3 && 
                   currentTextBox.SelectedText.Length == 0;
        }

        private void TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_suppressAddressUpdate)
            {
                Address = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", FirstSegment.Text, SecondSegment.Text, ThirdSegment.Text, LastSegment.Text);
            }

            var currentTextBox = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as TextBox;

            if (currentTextBox != null && currentTextBox.Text.Length == 3 && currentTextBox.CaretIndex == 3)
            {
                MoveFocusToNextSegment(currentTextBox);
            }
        }

        private bool ShouldCancelBackwardKeyPress()
        {
            var currentTextBox = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as TextBox;
            return currentTextBox != null && currentTextBox.CaretIndex == 0;
        }

        private void HandleBackspaceKeyPress()
        {
            var currentTextBox = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as TextBox;

            if (currentTextBox != null && currentTextBox.CaretIndex == 0 && currentTextBox.SelectedText.Length == 0)
            {
                MoveFocusToPreviousSegment(currentTextBox);
            }
        }

        private void HandleBackwardKeyPress()
        {
            var currentTextBox = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as TextBox;

            if (currentTextBox != null && currentTextBox.CaretIndex == 0)
            {
                MoveFocusToPreviousSegment(currentTextBox);
            }
        }

        private bool ShouldCancelForwardKeyPress()
        {
            var currentTextBox = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as TextBox;
            return currentTextBox != null && currentTextBox.CaretIndex == 3;
        }

        private void HandleForwardKeyPress()
        {
            var currentTextBox = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as TextBox;

            if (currentTextBox != null && currentTextBox.CaretIndex == currentTextBox.Text.Length)
            {
                MoveFocusToNextSegment(currentTextBox);
            }
        }

        private void HandlePeriodKeyPress()
        {
            var currentTextBox = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as TextBox;

            if (currentTextBox != null && currentTextBox.Text.Length > 0 && currentTextBox.CaretIndex == currentTextBox.Text.Length)
            {
                MoveFocusToNextSegment(currentTextBox);
            }
        }

        private void MoveFocusToPreviousSegment(TextBox currentTextBox)
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(currentTextBox, FirstSegment))
            {
                var previousSegmentIndex = _segments.FindIndex(box => ReferenceEquals(box, currentTextBox)) - 1;
                currentTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
                currentTextBox.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous));
                _segments[previousSegmentIndex].CaretIndex = _segments[previousSegmentIndex].Text.Length;
            }
        }

        private void MoveFocusToNextSegment(TextBox currentTextBox)
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(currentTextBox, LastSegment))
            {
                currentTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
                currentTextBox.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            }
        }

        private void DataObject_OnPasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
        {
            var isText = e.SourceDataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.UnicodeText, true);
            if (!isText)
            {
                e.CancelCommand();
                return;
            }

            var text = e.SourceDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText) as string;

            int num;

            if (!int.TryParse(text, out num))
            {
                e.CancelCommand();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code-behind is mostly handling different events:

- What should happen if the user presses backspace,
- What should happen if the user presses the left or right arrows,
- What should happen if the user presses the dot,
- What should happen if the user is trying to paste in something.

And so on and so on.

The usage is the following:

```
<ipTextBoxDemo:IPTextBox Width="150" Address="{Binding AddressInVM}"></ipTextBoxDemo:IPTextBox>
```

As you can see the `UserControl` exposes a `string` property called `Address` (binding two-way by default).

If the source of the binding changes (`AddressInVm` here, so change coming from the VM) then the `UserControl` will split the text by the dots and will put the resulting values in the four `TextBox`es.

If the target of the binding changes (the user types in something in the box), the four `TextBox`es' `Text` properties will be concatenated.

To make this proper you have to implement validation as well, because that is missing from this `UserControl`, but I leave that to you as an exercise ;)

The result:

[image: The result]

Comment: Szabolcs Thanks a lot . it was very helpful .You really saved my day

Comment: Just a future note, if you put a textbox next to this control, for say a Port input, the `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"` will cause the cursor bar to stay in the port textbox when it loses focus.

Comment: Hi, I have an issue but I am assuming it's something I am doing incorrectly. I have the ip user control in my code and if I enter a valid ip address once my app has run then it works very well. My issue is that I know in advanced the default IP address for my device and I set that at the start of my code: - just after InitializeComponent() I put  btIpAddress.Address = "192.168.0.237". This causes the control to show my address on startup but it gets reset in TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged because _suppressAddressUpdate is set to true. How do I pre initialize the control to an ip address?
        }

Comment: @ZedLepplin were you able to resolve this issue?