# User Input for polynomial functions

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, viewmodel

I need to create an application where the user can enter different polynomial functions. First the user has to select a certain grade of the polynomial function (between 0 and 10). On the basis of the selected grade there should appear different amount of textboxes where the user can specify the values for the coefficients. For example the user selects grade "4" -> 5 textboxes appear. It should look like this:

a4___ a3___ a2___ a1___ a0___

___: stands for a single textbox

I am also struggling to align the textboxes horizontally when using an ItemsControl.
I also want to save the values entered by the user in my ViewModel. I have already tried so many things but i can't figure it out how to do it. This is my code so far:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedGrade}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Height="20" Width="100"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

public ObservableCollection<double> SelectedGrade
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<double> newCol = new ObservableCollection<double>();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.SelectedNum + 1; i++)
            {
                newCol.Add(0);
            }

            this.selectedGrade = newCol;
            return newCol;
        }
        set
        {
            //...
        }
    }


public ICommand AddPolyFuncCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(obj =>
            {
                Function newPolyFunc = new PolyFunction(this.Coefficients);
                Functions.Add(newPolyFunc);
                CalculatePoints();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Yor are looking for masked Text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324285/how-to-create-masked-textbox-like-windows-ip-address-fields) this can help i gusses

Comment: I suggest to style a `ItemsControl` for the Input and bind it to an `ObservableCollection`. Then you can create as many entries as you need (grade 0-10) and when you styled it right, it will be displayed as you sketched.

Comment: @LittleBit Do you have a suggestion on how to align the textboxes horizontally? I have inserted my code on top.

Comment: You are on the right track, but unfortunately the Value/Text of the `TextBox` is not bound to the `SelectedGrade`. If you could specifiy waht the `SelectedGrade` is (`List<double>`, `ObservableCollection<double>`, other) i'll provide an Example as Answer.

Comment: Yes it is an Observablecollection<double>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Comments i'll provide a small Example how it could be done (i've added 1-2 extras which may be handy for this)

Use `Text="{Binding Value}"` to bind to the Value in the VM

Use a `Wrappanel` to display it horizontally

(optional) Use the `AlternationIndex` to label the Coefficients

(optional) Change the `FlowDirection` to display it like you sketched it

```
<!-- Combobox to select from the available Grades and store the selected in the SelectedGrade -->
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableGrades}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedGrade}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

<!-- Use Alternationcount to label the coefficients properly and Flowdirection to keep a0 on the right side -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Coefficients}" AlternationCount="11" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!-- Textbox to enter Coefficient (eg. a0 would be SelectedGrade[0] in code)-->
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <!-- Labeling of the Coefficient using the AlternationIndex and a String Format -->
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ContentStringFormat="a{0}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <!--  Use a WrapPanel as ItemsPanel to align the Entries horizontally -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

And looks like this (without the Grade Textbox, solely the stuff on the right side)
[image]

---

*EDIT*

To adjust the amount of coefficients properly there is a little bit logic needed, but first -> Rename the Properties appropriately and define their possible value (this helps to create the appropriate logic to the Properties)

> AvailableGrades = 0, 1, 2 ... 10
>
> SelectedGrade ∈ {0, 1, 2 ... 10}
>
> Coefficients = a(0), a(1) ... a(SelectedGrade)

```
//Unfortunately it is not possible to use a Value Type and bind to it due it has no Getter/Setter therefore we need a little wrapper
public class ValueTypeAsClass<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator ValueTypeAsClass<T>(T v)
    {
        return new ValueTypeAsClass<T> { Value = v };
    }
    public static implicit operator T(ValueTypeAsClass<T> v)
    {
        return v.Value;
    }
}

//member variable for select grade
private int _selectedGrade = 0;
//List of Coefficients (renamed from SelectedGrade)
public ObservableCollection<ValueTypeAsClass<double>> Coefficients { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ValueTypeAsClass<double>>() { 0d };
//Available (valid) Grades to select from in the ComboBox
public List<int> AvailableGrades { get; private set; } = Enumerable.Range(0, 11).ToList();
//Currently selected grad with logic to adjust the coefficient amount
public int SelectedGrade
{
    get { return _selectedGrade; }
    set
    {
        _selectedGrade = value;
        //Clear Coefficients and add the necessary amount
        Coefficients.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i <= _selectedGrade; i++) { Coefficients.Add(0); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That almost solved it. My only remaining problem is, how i can change the values of the coefficients in the viewModel (in the ObservableCollection) when i change them in the application.
I inserted the code of the property on top.

Comment: I would first rename the Properties to the "Thing" they represent (eg. SelectedGrade should not be a `Collection` of Coefficients, simply name  it "Coefficients" instead). When you separated the variables, you can add a little logic to the `SelectedGrade` Property and it will work as you expect (See the Edit in the Answer). If this fits your need i would appreciate when you mark it as answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much! The only thing that's not working is that the ObservableCollection of the Coefficients does not seem to update the values when i change them. I double checked it with a list view of the coefficients but the values just dont want to change.

Comment: @Felixbrandi Oh right, a value type has no getter/setter and can not be bound directly. I've added a small Wrapper class for ValueTypes. When you change the `Binding Path=.` to `Binding Value` it updates the Coefficients in the Viewmodel (you can use the Coefficients as usual like `Coefficient[0] = 3d;` etc). When something does not work, try to copy the whole code.

Comment: I have a problem when adding new functions to the ObservableCollection. Basically, all the latest functions are replaced with the function I am trying to add to the collection. For example, I added 3 different functions to the collection but inside the collection they are all the same. Do you have an idea on how I can fix this? I posted the command to add the functions to the collections on top.

Comment: @Felixbrandi I suggest you to create a new Question and post only the relevant code for saving/creating new Functions and refer to this question with a link. (I'll look into it when i can spare some time :) )